# Angular drag/drop: how to clone an element, drag newly-cloned element

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm working on UI that has elements which can be `draggable` or `cloneable`, using Angular 7 and the drag/drop functionality in the Angular CDK.

A `cloneable` element is stationary, and initiating a drag event on it should create a copy, make that copy draggable, and (ideally) use the drag event from the parent element to determine drag trajectory and drop location.

My current implementation creates the copy on dragend, and determines where it should be placed using `event.clientX` / `event.clientY`. However, Firefox returns 0 for both values, so I'm searching for other solutions.

Creating the clone and making it an Angular draggable item is easy. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to apply the parent-initiated drag event to the cloned element.

Any thoughts or pointers would be appreciated.